# Avoid sidenav refresh and change only the content div Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to avoid the sidenav to refresh each time I choose a category and only change the content section of the page. Can anyone help? TIA

Here's what I have so far

```
<body>

    @include('layouts.header')

    <main>
        <div class="container" style="background-color: white; height: 100%;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2" id="verticalNav">
                    @include('layouts.verticalNav')
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 text-center" id="content">
                    @yield('content')
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                    <h5>ADBANNERS!</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    @include('layouts.footer')
```

and here's my script

```
<script>
            $("#verticalNav").click(function(event){
              event.preventDefault();

              $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
            });
        </script>
```

the problem here is when I put # sidenav wont even click

Comment: Please state your problem clearly.

Comment: I wish for only the div for @yield('content') change whenever I try to choose a category from verticalNav. Because everytime I try to choose a category the whole page refreshes prompting me to scroll down yet again.

Comment: what really is going wrong with the `js` part to load content into the div?

Comment: problems with the script
-> it won't let me click anything on the sidenav if I put '#' for id
->even if I remove the '#' the whole page still refreshes after I choose a category on the sidenav

What I wish to happen is for only the <div id="content"> to refresh and not the whole app layout.

Comment: You shouldn't put `#` but rather `javascript:void`

Comment: ok imma try putting that instead